# str_remove works with vectors and data frames but not with tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, tibble

Please consider the following three examples:

```
library(tidyverse)

x_vector <- c("Device=iPhone", "Device=Samsung Galaxy")
x_df <- as.data.frame(c("Device=iPhone", "Device=Samsung Galaxy"))
x_tibble <- as_tibble(c("Device=iPhone", "Device=Samsung Galaxy"))
```

I now want to remove part of each string, i.e. the "Device=" sub string. It works for a vector, it also works for a data frame (if I specify the respective column), but I get a weird result for a tibble:

(the desired output would be the ones shown below for the vector and df example)

```
output_vector <- str_remove(x_vector, "Device=")
output_df <- str_remove(x_df[,1], "Device=")
output_tibble <- str_remove(x_tibble[,1], "Device=")
```

Can anyone please explain why this doesn't work with tibbles and how I can get it working with tibbles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `tibble` won't drop the dimensions when we do `[,1]`.  It is a still a `tibble` with a single column.

```
library(stringr)
class(x_tibble[,1])
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"   

class(x_df[,1]) 
#[1] "factor"
```

Instead, we can use `[[` to extract the column as a vector because `str_remove` expects a `vector` as input (`?str_remove` - `string` - Input vector. Either a character vector, or something coercible to one.)

```
str_remove(x_tibble[[1]], "Device=")
```